# IPTV player application in Android

Tags: android, media-player, iptv

I understood that there are many free iptv channels available for viewing. So I would like to develop an application to play these multicast-ed streams using my android media player.

Could somebody guide me on this.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 1):

I do this before... If you want only want to play multicast stream please add a `VideoView` to your `MainActivity`. For example:

```
 VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                selectedVideo++;
                play();
            }
        });

        play();
    }
```

And Play function code:

```
private void play() {
    String result = "udp://239.1.2.3:6001";

Uri video = Uri.parse(result);

if (videoView.isPlaying())
    videoView.stopPlayback();

videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        videoView.start();
    }
});
}
```

Note that you **must** have **Multicast Enabled Network** for playing multicast stream.

Answer (score 0):

I develop an personal example for that with ExoMedia. Here is the [link](https://github.com/enzoftware/android_iptv), but basically is a combination of a Service and PlaylistManager to play a multicast-ed streams

```
// PlaylistManager.kt
/**
 * A PlaylistManager that extends the [ListPlaylistManager] for use with the
 * [MediaService] which extends [com.devbrackets.android.playlistcore.service.BasePlaylistService].
 */
class PlaylistManager(application: Application) :
    ListPlaylistManager<ChannelItem>(application, MediaService::class.java) {

    /**
     * Note: You can call [.getMediaPlayers] and add it manually in the activity,
     * however we have this helper method to allow registration of the media controls
     * listener provided by ExoMedia's [com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoControls]
     */
    fun addVideoApi(videoApi: VideoApi) {
        mediaPlayers.add(videoApi)
        updateVideoControls(videoApi)
        registerPlaylistListener(videoApi)
    }

    /**
     * Note: You can call [.getMediaPlayers] and remove it manually in the activity,
     * however we have this helper method to remove the registered listener from [.addVideoApi]
     */
    fun removeVideoApi(videoApi: VideoApi) {
        videoApi.videoView.videoControls?.setButtonListener(null)

        unRegisterPlaylistListener(videoApi)
        mediaPlayers.remove(videoApi)
    }

    /**
     * Updates the available controls on the VideoView and links the
     * button events to the playlist service and this.
     *
     * @param videoApi The VideoApi to link
     */
    private fun updateVideoControls(videoApi: VideoApi) {
        videoApi.videoView.videoControls?.let {
            it.setPreviousButtonRemoved(true)
            it.setNextButtonRemoved(true)
            it.setButtonListener(ControlsListener())
        }
    }

    /**
     * An implementation of the [VideoControlsButtonListener] that provides
     * integration with the playlist service.
     */
    private inner class ControlsListener : VideoControlsButtonListener {
        override fun onPlayPauseClicked(): Boolean {
            invokePausePlay()
            return true
        }

        override fun onPreviousClicked(): Boolean {
            invokePrevious()
            return false
        }

        override fun onNextClicked(): Boolean {
            invokeNext()
            return false
        }

        override fun onRewindClicked(): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onFastForwardClicked(): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// MediaService.kt
/**
 * A simple service that extends [BasePlaylistService] in order to provide
 * the application specific information required.
 */
class MediaService : BasePlaylistService<ChannelItem, PlaylistManager>() {

    override val playlistManager by lazy { (applicationContext as App).playlistManager }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        // Adds the audio player implementation, otherwise there's nothing to play media with
        playlistManager.mediaPlayers.add(AudioApi(applicationContext))
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        // Releases and clears all the MediaPlayersMediaImageProvider
        playlistManager.mediaPlayers.forEach {
            it.release()
        }

        playlistManager.mediaPlayers.clear()
    }

    override fun newPlaylistHandler(): PlaylistHandler<ChannelItem> {
        val imageProvider = MediaImageProvider(applicationContext) {
            playlistHandler.updateMediaControls()
        }

        return DefaultPlaylistHandler.Builder(
            applicationContext,
            javaClass,
            playlistManager,
            imageProvider
        ).build()
    }
}
```