# How can I pre-adding IPTV links on apps

Tags: android, apk

I'm currently using "OTT Navigator" and "Tivimate" to see TV channels. Now I wanna pre-adding some IPTV links creates by myself in to this app (.apk files) to install on other devices.
How can I do it?

I've read some articles but could not find the answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VideoView to play multicast stream

```
VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            selectedVideo++;
            startVideo();
        }
    });

    startVideo();
}
```

Start Video Code:

```
private void startVideo() {
String result = "udp://257.5.1.4:8080"; // your desire Ip

Uri video = Uri.parse(result);

if (videoView.isPlaying())
videoView.stopPlayback();

videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    videoView.start();
}
});
}
```

**Helpful Post:**

> [IPTV player application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044889/iptv-player-application-in-android)